# Recursion not working as expected for target sum problem

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, recursive-query

I wrote two different recursive functions in python to solve the following problem. The second function I wrote works correctly and returns the correct result; but the first function I wrote returns a wrong result. The only difference between the two functions is the base condition. Could you please explain to me why the first function returns a wrong result?

Problem statement:

> **You are given an integer array `nums` and an integer `target`. You want to build an expression out of `nums` by adding one of the symbols
> '+' and '-' before each integer in nums and then concatenate all the
> integers.**
>
> For example, if `nums = [2, 1]`, you can add a '+' before 2 and a '-'
> before 1 and concatenate them to build the expression "+2-1".
>
> Return the number of different expressions that you can build, which
> evaluates to target.

My code:

```py
# first function: returns the wrong result
def targetsum(nums, crnt, target):
  print(nums,crnt)
  if target==crnt:
    return 1
  if len(nums)==0:
    return 0
  result = (
    targetsum(nums[1:], crnt + nums[0], target)
    + targetsum(nums[1:], crnt - nums[0], target)
  )
  return result

# second function: returns the correct result
def dfs(curr, nums, target):
  print(nums,curr)
  if not nums:
    return (1 if curr == target else 0)         
  res = (
    dfs(curr + nums[0], nums[1:], target)
    + dfs(curr - nums[0], nums[1:], target)
  )
  return res

nums = [1,1,1,1,1] 
target = 3
crnt=0

print(targetsum(nums, crnt, target))   # prints 4

print(dfs(crnt, nums, target))         # prints 5
```

I expected the output 5, because there are 5 ways to assign symbols to make the sum of `nums` be target 3:

```
    -1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
    +1 - 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
    +1 + 1 - 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
    +1 + 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 = 3
    +1 + 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 = 3
```

The second function, `dfs`, returns 5 as expected. But the first function, `targetsum`, returns 4 which is wrong. Why?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: you have managed to write code that solves your problem perfectly, but you don't know why it works?

Comment: @stef HI, means why the first code not getting exact answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base-case for the recursion is wrong in your first function `targetsum`. Function `targetsum` returns `1` immediately if `crnt == target`, *even if we haven't reached the end of the array*. But this is wrong: you should not return a result until you've reached the end of the array.

On your example with `nums=[1,1,1,1,1]` and `target=3`, the first recursive calls will go like this:

```
 1 1 1 1 1   crnt=0
+1 1 1 1 1   crnt=1
+1+1 1 1 1   crnt=2
+1+1+1 1 1   crnt=3
crnt==3==target!! return 1 immediately!!
```

Can you see the error in logic here? `crnt` is equal to target, yes, but we forgot to take into account the last two numbers in the array. We shouldn't return 1 immediately; in fact, there are not 1 but 2 possibilities to make target 3 with the beginning `+1+1+1`: the two possibilities are `+1+1+1+1-1` and `+1+1+1-1+1`. But the only way to figure that out is to go deeper in the recursion. We haven't hit a base-case yet.

Your second function `dfs` handles the base case correctly: the conditional `if not nums:` means "if `nums` is empty:".